# Is a variable with find static once it is set?

Tags: linux, bash

If I use the following in a bash script, is the variable set for the remainder of the script, or does it re-run the find command everytime the variable is called on?

`example=$(find /path/to/files -name "test")`

This is what I'm doing:

```
# sets new_tv_name variable
new_tv_name=$(find "$TR_TORRENT_DIR/$TR_TORRENT_NAME" -type f -not -size -100M -not -size +2G -not -iname "*sample*" \( -iname "*s[0-9]*" -o -iname "*s[0-9][0-9]*" -o -iname "*s[0-9][0-9][0-9]*" -o -iname "*e[0-9]*" -o -iname "*e[0-9][0-9]*" -o -iname "*e[0-9][0-9][0-9]*" -o -iname "*s[0-9][0-9]e[0-9][0-9]*" -o -iname "*s[0-9][0-9]e[0-9][0-9][0-9]*" -o -iname "*s[0-9][0-9][0-9]e[0-9][0-9][0-9]*" -o -iname "*s[0-9]e[0-9][0-9]*" -o -iname "*s[0-9]e[0-9][0-9][0-9]*" -o -iname "*[0-9]x[0-9]*" -o -iname "*[0-9]x[0-9][0-9]*" -o -iname "*[0-9][0-9]x[0-9][0-9]*" -o -iname "*[0-9][0-9][0-9]x[0-9][0-9][0-9]*" -o -iname "*hdtv*" \) -exec basename {} \;)

# sets new_tv_directory variable
new_tv_directory=$(find "$TR_TORRENT_DIR/$TR_TORRENT_NAME" -type f -not -size -100M -not -size +2G -not -iname "*sample*" \( -iname "*s[0-9]*" -o -iname "*s[0-9][0-9]*" -o -iname "*s[0-9][0-9][0-9]*" -o -iname "*e[0-9]*" -o -iname "*e[0-9][0-9]*" -o -iname "*e[0-9][0-9][0-9]*" -o -iname "*s[0-9][0-9]e[0-9][0-9]*" -o -iname "*s[0-9][0-9]e[0-9][0-9][0-9]*" -o -iname "*s[0-9][0-9][0-9]e[0-9][0-9][0-9]*" -o -iname "*s[0-9]e[0-9][0-9]*" -o -iname "*s[0-9]e[0-9][0-9][0-9]*" -o -iname "*[0-9]x[0-9]*" -o -iname "*[0-9]x[0-9][0-9]*" -o -iname "*[0-9][0-9]x[0-9][0-9]*" -o -iname "*[0-9][0-9][0-9]x[0-9][0-9][0-9]*" -o -iname "*hdtv*" \) -exec dirname {} \;)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any case where `foo=$(bar)` is run only invokes `bar` once, when the command is executed; this behavior is generic to the shell, and not in any way specific to `find`.

---

On a different point -- storing the output from `find` that way is ambiguous: You'd need to force a newline as separator to iterate through multiple results without filenames with whitespace tripping you up, and even then, filenames can legitimately contain newlines in UNIX.

Better to NUL-delimit your files and use an array, if you want your code to work properly in all corner cases:

```
example=( )
while IFS= read -r -d '' filename; do
  example+=( "$filename" )
done < <(find /path/to/files -name test -print0)

printf 'Found file: %q\n' "${example[@]}" # print all files found, with unprintable
                                          # characters escaped.
```

If you're recording these names just to pass them to a command, by contrast, you can tell `find` to run that command itself, and not need to store them in shell at all. See sections 5 ("Actions") and 6 ("Complex Actions") in [UsingFind](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind) for details.

Comment: @Charles_Duffy I added an example of what I'm doing. It works perfectly. I just needed to know If I needed to redirect the output to a temp file, and use that to set another variable.

Comment: @DavidCuster, that may work perfectly in the simple cases you're testing it in, but add some filenames with newlines in their paths that match your expression -- or, if you're assuming only one match, add a second one -- and I promise it won't.

Comment: @Charles_Duffy So it's static?

Comment: Yes, it's static. If you wanted something dynamic, you'd be using a function instead of a variable assignment.

Comment: @Charles_Duffy **Perfect!** _Static_ was the answer I was looking for. Thank you!